# Numbers app: conditional highlighting using color scales?

Tags: numbers

Is this possible, like you can in other spreadsheet software to do something like this? (color scales)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional highlighting - this doesn't provide *quite* that high level of automation, as you have to add rules one-by-one - but you can automate values with all sorts of controls. Find the main menu in Format -> Cell -> Conditional Highlighting...
**Here is the main menu:**

[image]

You have options such as:
**Numbers | Text | Date | Duration | Blank**

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This isn’t really viable if you have more than a handful of distinct values

Comment: @BallpointBen I agree, Excel wins in efficiency here. It would be great to see Numbers implement something similar to what CarlesAlcolea was looking for. However, I am simply trying to provide an alternative to something which is not currently implemented. If you have a better solution I'm sure it would be welcome.

Comment: I appreciate your intention, but obviously, that's the first place I checked and it's a bit of insanity to bend the user that way. I wanted to confirm if Pages really didn't have that feature, and it seems it doesn't have it.

Comment: Been so long since I used Excel that I don't remember enough to compare, but I find LibreOffice Calc as good as Excel and better than Numbers.  It also has a feature like this.